# галерея с разными цветами

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть несколько картинок разных цветов(красный,зелёный,жёлтый), как с помощью jquery сделать сортировку по цвету, т.е нажимаешь на красный цвет, все фотографии выводятся с красным цветом. 
jquery только изучаю, можете скинуть мануалы или что почитать , спасибо.

Comment: Не думаю что Вы понимаете слово AJAX. Оно означает асинхронную загрузку файлов в кеш браузера и выполнение с этими файлами действий, то что Вы говорите - чистой воды JavaScript.

Comment: ой, не аякс, JQuery  что-то да)

Answer (score 0):

1. Пометьте каждое изображение тегами соответствующих цветов (например, добавив к соответствующим html-элементам атрибут data-colors)
2. Обойдите все элементы и скройте (удалите) те, в data-color которых нет выбранного цвета

```js
var $pictures = $('.picture');
var selectedColor = 'red';
$pictures.each(function() {
  var colors = $(this).data('colors');
  if (colors.indexOf(selectedColor) === -1) {
   $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picture" data-colors="[&quot;red&quot;,&quot;pink&quot;]">
  1
  ...
</div>
<div class="picture" data-colors="[&quot;green&quot;,&quot;blue&quot;]">
  2
  ...
</div>
<div class="picture" data-colors="[&quot;red&quot;]">
  3
  ...
</div>
```

Данные о том какого цвета картинка вы можете получать откуда угодно или даже вычислять во время выполнения. Вычисление основного оттенка изображения довольно интересная задача, хотя можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь готовым решением (например [dominant-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dominant-color)). Получив основной оттенок можно "округлить" его до одного или нескольких базовых цветов, по которым будете фильтровать.